# Fluent Security and AOP with CastleDynamicProxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-security

This exact problem has been asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/pull/43) but the provided workaround just doesnt seem to be optional with version 2.

The problem is, that if security is configured properly, even when it is configured via ForAllControllersInheriting, it just doesnt work with the CastleDynamixProxy runtime created Controllers proxies.

I suppose this is caused by the fact that these controllers actually do not exist when fluent security is parsing the rules. Is there any workaround for this? I wanted to create customized HandleSecurityAttribute as suggested on [GitHub](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/pull/43) , but I wasnt able to do it with all the internal stuff in version 2 (but that may be the cause that I am no professional at C#, so I may just need a hint how to do that).

I tried all possible configurations:

```
configuration.ForAllControllersInAssembly(typeof(HomeController).Assembly)
    .DenyAnonymousAccess();
configuration.ForAllControllersInheriting<HomeController>().DenyAnonymousAccess();
configuration.ForAllControllers().DenyAnonymousAccess();
```

None of those seems to work with this issue.

Comment: I've posted an answer to your comment on github. Let me know what you need and I am sure we can come up with something that will solve this issue. When we have it working, we can post the final result here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who still wonder how to solve this, there is a way in using a customized authorizatin attribute with a little help of SecurityHandler.

```
public class CastleProxyHandleSecurityAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{

    private readonly ISecurityHandler securityHandler;

    public CastleProxyHandleSecurityAttribute()
    {
        securityHandler = new SecurityHandler();
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.FullName;

        if (controllerName.StartsWith("Castle") && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.BaseType != null)
        {
            controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.BaseType.FullName;
        }

        var securityContext = SecurityContext.Current;
        securityContext.Data.RouteValues = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

        var overrideResult = securityHandler.HandleSecurityFor(controllerName, actionName, securityContext);
        if (overrideResult != null) filterContext.Result = overrideResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: We'll see if we can make this easier in FluentSecurity 3.0. Thanks for posting a solution...